# Unsure how to add an oval to an image. Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, image-trace

I am new with AI, this may be easy.

I am trying to make an earring for laser engraving.

I imported a jpg (also tried transparent gif) Ive traced it.

I am trying to add half an oval for the earring part.

As you can see, I can't get the hoop to place on the top of the image, since the image is square it's not matching up and getting the border.  Not sure how to go about this. And I hope I explained it well enough.

[image]

Comment: This is somehow interesting. Let's assume your half oval finally is properly connected with the black body of your shape. The white area in the middle of the half oval is a hole for the hanging hook of the earring. Right? If yes, then: What is the rest of the white in the middle of your shape.? What are you going to do with the six smaller black pieces?

Comment: The A will be blank wood, the laser will engrave the black, the A wont be cut out.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you used the *Image Trace* feature.

*Image Trace* will also trace the white border around the picture (as its own path). The slim white border that seems to be covering up your hoop, just has to be removed.

- Go ahead and click on *Expand*. This will expand (for lack of a better word) all your items into individual vector paths.
- Ungroup the items (*right click → Ungroup*; <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>**G**</kbd>)
- Select the white border and remove it.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to do it!  I appreciate it, spent at least 5-6 hours trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Not too certain on what exactly you're asking help on but maybe my question can help solve part of your problem. 
Have you trying making the oval longer so that it passes behind or over the logo and then use "Shapebuilder Tool" or "Pathfinder" to merge the difference shapes together?

Comment: Not an answer... better added as a comment